# Which Image Quality Metric should I use in this case (Binary Segmented Images)?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I have some ground truth Image that I want to compare with my automatic segmentation code. I need some help to choose the correct Image Quality Metric, I've heard about ssmi,psnr, but knowing that I'm working with binary images, I think I need a different kind of Metric. Do you guys have any idea?

Ground Truth Image:
[image: Ground truth Image]

My segmentation code:
[image: SegmentedAutomaticly]

Comment: Hausdorff-Distance with some optimizations might be a good metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comparing segmentation masks, PSNR and SSIM are not very good measures.

You should look at Intersection over Union (IoU) of the output mask and the ground truth. Or the distance of the boundary pixels from the ground truth.

[Berkeley segmentation dataset](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/) focuses on the task of image segmentation and boundary detection, which seems closely related to your task. You can check out their methods for evaluating segmentation results.

Comment: I'm new on this so I might say dumb things ..Intersection over Union (IoU) is pretty good for binary images, but I'm working with skeletonized image, and it might happen that I have an output very similar to the ground truth but if they aren't in the same position I won't get good results. I'll see about Berkeley segmentation dataset . What do you think about SNR or Hausdorff-Distance ? i also thought about SSIM but just the structural part of the formula.